# How to stop child widgets from being drawn above parent borders?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to stop the `PushButtons` being drawn above the parent borders?

Quick example:

[image]

Only `widget` has something set into the `style sheet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the margins in the layout section of `widget`, scroll to the bottom of widget's info and there should be layoutLeftMargin etc.